# loop through array to find a certain word then print all objects containing the word

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm not sure if what I am asking makes sense, but I'll try explain the best I can. I have some JSON data which I've printed out by using cURL and, one part of the object prints out like so,

Domestic Beer (0.5 liter draught), Restaurants

and then next line would be

Loaf of Fresh White Bread (500g), Markets

I was wondering if it is possible to loop through the array of data and see which parts contain the word 'restaurants' and group them all together into a variable, and then do the same for makets?

This is my code for the arrays so far

```
            $json = json_decode($r);
            $json->monthLastUpdate;
            // search through data for printing
             echo "<div id='results'>";
            echo "<h2> Prices for $country </h2>";

            foreach($json->prices as $prices) {
                // echos out the selected items into a list
            echo "</div>";


            echo "<p>"  . $prices->item_name . " <br><b> Average price </b>";
                    $pricedata ="$prices->average_price";

               //rounds the numbers down to readable format

            echo number_format((float)$pricedata, 2, '.', '');
            echo  "&#40;";
            echo $currency;
            echo "&#41;";
```

This is the JSON data that I am receiving from the query

```
    {
       "monthLastUpdate": 3,
      "contributors": 4424,
     "name": "India",
     "prices": [
           {
             "average_price": 0.984819890047,
                "item_name": "Meal, Inexpensive Restaurant, Restaurants",
             "highest_price": 1.96963978009,
               "item_id": 1,
              "lowest_price": 0.64013292853
          },
          {
               "average_price": 4.92409945023,
               "item_name": "Meal for 2, Mid-range Restaurant, Three-course, Restaurants",
                "highest_price": 7.87855912037,
               "item_id": 2,
                "lowest_price": 3.0005
           },
```

Comment: How consistent is the position of that comma - can you split the line by that? Maybe post a little bit of your JSON code

Comment: I added the JSON to make a bit more sense, I'm trying to get it so at the end the bit with Restaurants will be in a separate group and the same would go for Markets etc. I can't remove the comma's as the data is coming from an external source

Comment: `list($item_name, $restaurant_name, $type) = explode(',', $prices->item_name);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If formatting is consistent and assuming you don't have any commas in the item name, you can do something like this:

```
$itemCatalog = array();

foreach($items as $item){
    $chunks = explode("," $item);
    $category = $chunks[1];
    $itemName = $chunks[0];

    $itemCatalog[$category][] = $itemName;
}
```

Afterwards you'll have a multi-dimensional array filled with items sorted by category.